# Force Full Postback programmatically from UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a GridView in an update panel. It's an inherited asp:GridView, so it has a little "export me" icon which does just that. It works by responding to an "export" click with an XLS file. The problem is that if you put the smart GridView inside an update panel, ASP.NET thinks the XLS file is to be written into the panel, which is obviously not what we want. For this, I need a full post-back every time.

My update panels are all programmatically generated

Solutions which don't work in this precise scenario (many of which are covered elsewhere on SO):

1. In ASP.NET before version 4, if you left the ID off a control it would do a full postback even from within an update panel. My question is for the latest and greatest .NET 4 only.
2. ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl looks promising. It does make the control post-back use the correct panel ID as the eventtarget, but doesn't otherwise help.
3. Adding a PostBackTrigger to the Update panel. My update panels are generated programmatically, and MS state that this is not supported. My tests indicate that they're right: I tried it every way, but this does not work.
4. I don't really like the idea of the smart GridView having to break out from itself, but I tried to make it put an extra control outside the updatePanel in these circumstances. The idea being to make a client-side click on my export button inside the panel be redirected by client javascript to simulate a click on that button outside the panel. However this doesn't work because I can't apparently add the "outside" control to the page - I get the "The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases." error.
5. Using jQuery to shift the "export" control outside the panel. MS must have some list of controls which they think are "in" the panel, and the physical location within the DOM doesn't matter.

Does anyone have any ideas how to make that work? I know a lot of this *should* work, but that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

For me, solution 3 works.

I dynamically add an `UpdatePanel` to the page, add a `Button` to the content template and associate a `PostBackTrigger`. I added a `Click` event handler in which I update a label (outside of the `UpdatePanel`) with the current date/time.

See my test setup below.

**Markup**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buttonId = "Button1";

    UpdatePanel updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
    updatePanel.ID = "UpdatePanel1";

    Button button = new Button();
    button.ID = "Button1";
    button.Text = "Post back";
    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

    updatePanel.Triggers.Add(new PostBackTrigger() { ControlID = buttonId});

    updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(button);

    Panel1.Controls.Add(updatePanel);
}

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = string.Format("Current date/time: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work that way for me. If I add the "postBackTrigger" when I create the panels, it fails if the button.ID is not already present (reasonable), but if I add it in my custom control it doesn't have any effect - suggests some life cycle thing. I'll stick at it.

Comment: If I put the button control into the page at OnInit() of the control which contains the update panels, that works as suggested. If instead I put it where I need it, in the OnInit() of the custom control inside the panel (searching back up the control hierarchy to find the update panel), then it does not work. More experimentation..

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but checkout this question (specifically the answer): [FileUpload in FormView inside an UpdatePanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555917/fileupload-in-formview-inside-an-updatepanel)

Comment: I'd looked at most of those questions, but not seen the subtlety of that answer. I'll try that tomorrow.

For now, I put a linkButton into all my update panels which is invisible. Then in the custom GridView within the panel I find that and hook an export event handler to it. Finally I get jQuery to move the control into the grid. That works perfectly, but it's a crime against nature!

Answer (score 3):

I realise this was asked a year ago but if it helps anyone else, solution 2 worked for me.

```
((ScriptManager)this.Page.Master.FindControl("scrptmgr")).RegisterPostBackControl(lnkbtn);
```

The only way I can get it to work is if the control (in this case lnkbtn) is visible when the above line of code runs.

**Edit** - After more testing it now seems that this method only works if there are no postbacks in between registering the control to do a full postback and actually clicking the thing. The solution or hack is to register the control to do a full postback on each page load.

Comment: Interesting - I worked around it another way (can't remember how). The "postbacks" caveat may be why this didn't work for me.

Comment: Saved my evening. In my case, I had my own event which was only bound to the main control which contained the UpdatePanel. My code in OnInit of the page: anlagenSelector.SelectionChanged += anlagenSelector_SelectionChanged;
((ScriptManager)this.Page.Master.FindControl("scriptManager")).RegisterPostBackControl(anlagenSelector);

Answer (score 0):

I built a similar inherited GridView control with the ability to do CSV export. The way I handled it is to make the export button a simple `<a href>` to the current page with a specially-crafted querystring parameter `"?SortablePagableGridViewExportToCSV=XXX"` where XXX is the `UniqueID` of my control. I override the Render method of my control, and in there I check the request parameters manually to see if that export param was sent. If so, I write the CSV content type header and response as below.

```
Me.Page.Response.Clear()
Me.Page.Response.ClearContent()
Me.Page.Response.ClearHeaders()
Me.Page.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Me.Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Me.ExportToCsvFileName)
Me.Page.Response.End()
```

The key is the call to `Page.Response.End()`, which stops all further processing. This is a GET request so I don't have to worry about UpdatePanel asynch postbacks or anything like that. The browser behaves beautifully in this situation, popping up the download link but keeping the user on the current page. The browser URL does not change, and the user can even right-click the download link and use Save Target As... if they wish.

Comment: You definitely need the "response" stuff, but my question is a little more specific. The problem is that the MS code which deals with their update panels "snaffles" the downloaded file. Outside an update panel it works as you describe, but not inside.

Comment: @philw, Have you tried this technique yourself? It's working for me from within an UpdatePanel using .NET 4.0. The UpdatePanel shouldn't matter at all in this case because it's not posting back at all, but rather doing a normal GET request, which doesn't get trapped by any of the UpdatePanel AJAX code.

Comment: The response stuff, of course - you need to add content length too or you will not get any progress indicators. I think (from memory) I can't actually remember how we fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In case the control that should force the page postback (suppose a button) is --inside-- a GridView templatefield, you may have some problems setting the controlId for the UpdatePanel trigger... in this case you can simply go to the teemplatefield button and set its "PostBackUrl" property to... the same page itself!

This way, clicking it, it will force a full postback...